# Unix script to resolve hostnames from IP addresses

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've got a text file with a bunch of IPv4 addresses, and I'd like to know the hostname of each one  in order to know if they are tor addresses. Is there a simple script that can help me to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop using dig:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
    dig -x "$line" +short
done
```

Then given IPs 1 per line, you can run something like `./reverse.sh < addrs.txt`.

Caveats: DNS is not a 1-to-1 mapping, and reverse DNS is somewhat less reliable than forward DNS.